# How to parse custom formatted file R

Tags: r, parsing, graph

This is a question raised from an impatient person who has started working R just now.
I have a file containing lines like this:

```
simulation_time:386300;real_time:365;agents:300

simulation_time:386800;real_time:368;agents:300

simulation_time:386900;real_time:383;agents:300

simulation_time:387000;real_time:451;agents:300

simulation_time:387100;real_time:345;agents:300

simulation_time:387200;real_time:327;agents:300

simulation_time:387300;real_time:411;agents:300

simulation_time:387400;real_time:405;agents:300

simulation_time:387500;real_time:476;agents:300

simulation_time:387600;real_time:349;agents:300 

....
```

need to plot a graph out of the file. [This link](https://www.harding.edu/fmccown/r/) teaches how to plot a file by reading a file in tabular format. But the above lines are not in tabular or a neat csv format.

Could you please tell me how to parse such a file?

Besides, if you have a reference for the the impatients like me, please let me know.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the structure of the file is strict, then you can customise you reading to get the data you want.
See the code below.

```
# reading the file 
strvec = readLines(con = "File.txt", n = -1)  
# strsplit by ";" or ":"
strlist = strsplit(strvec,":|;")
# changing to matrix (works only if the structure of each line is the same)
strmat = do.call(rbind, strlist)
# lets take only numbers
df = strmat[ ,c(2,4,6)]
# defining the names
colnames(df) = strmat[1 ,c(1,3,5)]
# changing strings to numerics (might be better methods, have any suggestions?)
df = apply(df, 2, as.numeric)
# changing to data.frame
df = as.data.frame(df)
# now you can do that ever you want
plot(df$simulation_time, type="l")
```

Comment: Spacedman's answer is more professional. But this one is better for a beginner as it has broken it down to several steps. thank you both

Answer (score 4):

For data in that exact format:

```
d = read.csv(textConnection(gsub(";",":",readLines("data.csv"))),sep=":",head=FALSE)[,c(2,4,6)]
```

produces:

```
       V2  V4  V6
1  386300 365 300
2  386800 368 300
3  386900 383 300
4  387000 451 300
```

you can then assign names to the data frame with `names(d)=c("sim","real","agents")`.

It works by reading the file into a character vector, replacing the ";" with ":" so everything is separated by ":", then using `read.csv` to read that text into a data frame, and then taking only the data columns and not the repeated text columns.